# How to execute the sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I execute this function?

I tried as `Select [dbo].[GetPaidInfo]("1")`, but I get the error:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
>   function dbo.GetPaidInfo.

```
USE [PCJ_BM]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetPaidInfo]    Script Date: 3/24/2018 5:05:15 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPaidInfo] (
    @InvId INT
    ,@PmtType VARCHAR(10)
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @PaidInfo NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @payment2 VARCHAR(50) = ''
    DECLARE @payment3 VARCHAR(50) = ''
    DECLARE @card VARCHAR(50) = (
            SELECT Card
            FROM Payment
            WHERE (InvId = @InvId)
            )
    DECLARE @Currency2 VARCHAR(50) = (
            SELECT Currency2
            FROM Payment
            WHERE (InvId = @InvId)
            )
    DECLARE @Amt2 VARCHAR(50) = (
            SELECT Amt2
            FROM Payment
            WHERE (InvId = @InvId)
            )
    DECLARE @Currency3 VARCHAR(50) = (
            SELECT Currency3
            FROM Payment
            WHERE (InvId = @InvId)
            )
    DECLARE @Amt3 VARCHAR(50) = (
            SELECT Amt3
            FROM Payment
            WHERE (InvId = @InvId)
            )

    IF (@PmtType = 'Cash')
    BEGIN
        IF (@Currency2 != NULL OR @Currency2 != '')
        BEGIN
            SET @payment2 = ' + ' + @Currency2 + ' ' + @Amt2
        END

        IF (@Currency3 != NULL OR @Currency3 != '')
        BEGIN
            SET @payment3 = ' + ' + @Currency3 + ' ' + @Amt3
        END

        SET @PaidInfo = (
                SELECT 'Paid in Cash by ' + Currency1 + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Amt1) + @payment2 + @payment3
                FROM Payment
                WHERE (InvId = @InvId)
                )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @PaidInfo = (
                SELECT 'Paid in Card by ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Amt1) --, Currency2, Amt2, Currency3, Amt3
                FROM Payment
                WHERE (InvId = @InvId)
                )
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @PaidInfo
END
```

My table looks like:

[image]

Comment: i need to execute this sql function

Comment: Of course it is not working, your functions needs **two** parameters you are only providing one. And it is an int and a varchar. For varchar always use single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function like this (`INT` no quotes, `VARCHAR(10)` single quotes):

```
SELECT [dbo].[GetPaidInfo] (1,'Cash');
```

Be aware your function returns `NVARCHAR(200)`.
It appears you are planning to concatenate some information there, so if you start to see some of your string truncated, you might want to increase the length.

Answer (score -1):

As per function definition, it requires 2 params : @InvId & @PmtType.

You should pass both of them during function call like follows:-

```
SELECT dbo.GetPaidInfo(2, 'Card');
```